Preserve cell/column formatting when adding rows in ExcelJs
I'm making a Next.js app but I've run into a problem.
The problem: I want to add some data into an Excel sheet which has a template. I'm currently using ExcelJs to do so. Adding data into the columns is fine and works as intended, but adding rows messes up the cell width or the column width. The template contains an image with differently sized colored cells, and adding a row also removes that image.
Is there any way to do this without messing up the formatting? Is there another library I should try besides ExcelJs that will not disrupt the formatting? Alternatively, is there another method to achieve this goal without relying on libraries?
I'm currently using:
worksheet.spliceRows(currentRow + i, 0, []);

to add a new row. I've also tried using:
worksheet.addRow();

but it also messes up the whole size formatting
